# Play Framework commands abort with ZipException

Tags: playframework-2.0

After a Windows 7 crash my Play framework project seems to be broken.

My version:

```
play --version
sbt launcher version 0.12.2
```

Running any play command in my project folder gives this error:

```
C:\dev\myproject>play clean
[info] Loading project definition from C:\dev\myproject\project
Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:13)
        at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:36)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:704)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:703)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
        at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:703)
        at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
        at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
        at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:29)
        at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:23)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:621)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:617)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:91)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$gzipInputStream$1.apply(Using.scala:91)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$1.openImpl(Using.scala:56)
        at sbt.WrapUsing$$anonfun$open$2.apply(Using.scala:36)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.translate(ErrorHandling.scala:11)
        at sbt.WrapUsing.open(Using.scala:36)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:704)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$gzipFileIn$1.apply(IO.scala:703)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)
        at sbt.IO$.gzipFileIn(IO.scala:703)
        at sbt.Sync$.readUncaught(Sync.scala:88)
        at sbt.Sync$.readInfo(Sync.scala:84)
        at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:29)
        at sbt.Sync$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Sync.scala:23)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:621)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$copyResourcesTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:617)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
        at sbt.Scoped$$anonfun$hf5$1.apply(Structure.scala:581)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:49)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.Scoped$Reduced$$anonfun$combine$1$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(Structure.scala:311)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:41)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$5.work(System.scala:71)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:238)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:232)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (compile:copy-resources) Error wrapping InputStream in GZIPInputStream: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP
format
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
[error] Not a valid command: clean (similar: last, eval)
[error] clean
[error]      ^
```

Googling did not help.
The stacktrace does not help me either, it doesn't say which file/resource causes that.
I have not made any changes to the project.
The only "difference" is the Windows crash, possibly while some play command was running.

Re-created play installation... same error.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To fix this you have to delete the "project" and "target" folders. They can be found in another folder called "project" in your play-project.

Comment: By now 8 people upvoted this answer, so I assume it works for most. I did not try it myself. I'm marking it as the correct answer now. Else you can still get a new code checkout (see below).

Comment: Make sure you really find them all:  
    rm -rf \`find . -name target\`

Comment: Came across this issue while trying to build PredictionIO locally. Solution worked for me.

Comment: OMG. Amazing error handling there. Thanks for wasting my time once again, Shitty Build Tool.

Answer (score 3):

Dunno what caused it, or how to properly solve it. And a meaningful exception would be nice.

But the workaround for me was to get a **new checkout from version control**.

Comment: Looks like it was a corrupted file then. Sometimes deleting the cached libraries from the sbt repository helps too.

Comment: I deleted the files and didn't work. Checking out from master fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent the last 4 hours trying to fix this error and it turned out that another folder in my home directory(ubuntu) was named project. Renaming this folder solved this issue for me.